# Bin Packing for item sizes with probabilitic distribution

Tags: variables, probability, distribution, packing

I have a number of objects sizes with the normal distribution (only positive values constraint by value S) and I want to pack them all to a minimum number of bins.

In other word, items are having variable sizes based on their probability distribution and bins are having fixed size b which is greater than S but still may require multiple of them to pack all the items . Do you know if this type of problem is been investigated or not?

Comment: As currently worded, having 1 bin meets your criteria.  I suspect you want to rethink and clarify what you mean by "pack them all to a minimum number of bins."

Comment: on top of @pjs question, do you realize that normal distribution is from -infinity to +infinity? How do you want to handle leftmost and rightmost bins?

Comment: @pjs - It depends on the size of the items and bins. In general, I may need more than one bin.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux - I assume it would get only positive values of Normal distribution.

Comment: So, you're getting half of the distribution going from 0 to +infinity. How rightmost bin shall be handled? You HAVE to give more info how do you think outcome should look...

Comment: @Sija You say in your comment "it depends on the size of the items and bins."  That's nowhere in your question, and it's still not enough info.  You really need to think this through and reword your question.  Believe it or not, I'm trying to help you avoid down-voting or close-voting, but you're making that a challenge.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux - I edited the problem definition to have items with variable sizes in range (0, S].

Comment: @pjs - I reparaphrased the question but I expect the readers to know the basic definition of bin packing problem to be able to help. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Please read the [help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) about how to ask questions.  Pay particular attention to items 1 and 4.  Your edit has made the question into a violation of #4.

Comment: @Sija Despite the fact that this question needs work, this problem is usually tackled by [stochastic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_programming) (which might give some headaches to newcomers)